# Did Jesus command the former invalid to do something unlawful at John 5:8?

Tags: john, law, sabbath

John 5:8-10 says

> "8 Then Jesus told him, “Get up, **pick up your mat, and walk**.” 9
> Immediately the man was made well, and he picked up his mat and began
> to walk. Now this happened on the Sabbath day, 10 so the Jews said to
> the man who had been healed, “**This is the Sabbath! It is unlawful
> for you to carry your mat**.”"

Were the Jews correct when they said it was 'unlawful' for the man to carry his mat on the Sabbath?

Note [related question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/68346/what-law-of-moses-forbade-the-lame-man-from-carrying-his-pallet-on-the-sabbath) about the law of Moses and the lame man. This one's broader, and is simply asking if the the Jews were correct to state it was 'unlawful'.

Comment: It is basically the same que related to sabbath breaking topics; you're only asking if it was an accurate interpretation. All the context show that there is no absolute rules forbidding all work or load bearing. It was their corrupted traditional interpretation, not accurate. They ignored the greater commands and values for the sake of their ritual demands.

Comment: @agarza Possibly. I have already linked to it in the question. My question here is whether the command could be unlawful in a broader sense (not just breaking a law of Moses).